# SVG image map with mouseover – make data "stick" on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have created an image map using [this plugin](https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/).

When you mouseover a state, it shows you the name of the state you've hovered over. However, if you click on a state, I'd like for its data to remain static until you re-click the state to release. I can't figure out how to do this.

Here's a codepen of what I have so far:
**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOZeBB**

I've tried to `unbind` the mouseover on click, which worked, but I couldn't figure out how to rebind it when you re-click the state:

```
 $('#map').usmap({
    mouseover: function(event, data) {
      $('#selected-state > span').text(data.name);
    },
     click: function(event, data) {
      $('#selected-state > span').text(data.name);
      $('#map path').unbind('mouseover');
    }
  });
```

Is there a way to use both mouseover and click functions together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just setting a global variable:

```
 var selectedMap = null;
 $('#map').usmap({
    mouseover: function(event, data) {
      if ( selectedMap == null ) {
          $('#selected-state > span').text(data.name);
      }
    },
    click: function(event, data) {
      $('#selected-state > span').text(data.name);
      selectedMap = data.name;
    }
  });
```

To "unstick" it after it's clicked again, use [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjObqW).

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, and though it works to hold the data on click, it doesn't reactivate the data change on hover again after you've re-clicked the state to "release it". See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyOqee